# JavaScript New Date formats

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to achieve this date format..

I'm getting my date from back-end, but its in server time. It looks like this

```
var d.date = "2017-04-26 07:49:09"
```

Then, I'm formatting it so date constructor would accept the format properly

```
var dateFormated = d.date.replace(' ', 'T');
```

Then, out of it I'm constructing my date object as follows:

```
var dateplublished = new Date(dateFormated);
```

Which gives me the following result :

```
Wed Apr 26 2017 07:49:09 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)
```

Everything seems to be fine, except that the GMT +0300 won't add. It supposed to spit out :

```
Wed Apr 26 2017 10:49:09 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)
```

How can I achieve this, so it Would be supported in all major browsers including ios safari etc? I managed to do it before, by doing it like so :

```
var dateFormated = d.date;
var dateplublished = new Date(dateFormated + " " + "UTC");
```

This way it would spit out everything perfectly, except that it would show NaN-NaN-NaN on ios safari/chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can all `Z` at the end of date. That way `new Date(2017-04-26T07:49:09Z);` will be resolved to your local time.

Answer (score 0):

Date parsing is best with momentjs.
It's much more reliable and provides cross-browser support.

Then you can use this to achieve what you're trying to do: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

Comment: Thank You, I know about moment, but I did not want to use any libraries. Accepted answer above solved my problem in vanilla js!

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.